# SQL issues, How can i separate this row of data into multiple column. i want it to separate by the pipe | and put it in its columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to separate a one-row data into multiple columns, and I have a pipe | between each data that I wanted to be separated.

I want this one-row data to split into a multi column

```
1234 |abcd | 123abc | some | more | 0922
```

to Be like this

```
col1   col2  col3     col4   col5    col6
1234   abcd  123abc   some   more    0922 


select 

[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)-1) --does what it suppose to
,[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|', PostData)-1) --does what it suppose to

,[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|',   PostData)-1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|',    PostData)-1) --i need help with this


,[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|', PostData)-1)--i need help with this
,[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|', PostData)-1)--i need help with this
,[Col1] = SUBSTRING(PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1,CHARINDEX('|',PostData,CHARINDEX('|',PostData)+1)-CHARINDEX('|', PostData)-1) --i need help with this

,[ID]   = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(PostData),0,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(PostData) --does what
```

it suppose to

from tableName

```
col1   col2  col3     col4   col5    col6
1234   abcd  123abc   some   more    0922
```

what I am getting is:

```
col1   col2  col3   col4    col5    col6
1234   abcd  abcd   abcd     abcd    0922
```

Comment: The short answer is to never, ever, store data like this. You've run into one problem it causes; there are more waiting for you. Sorry....

Comment: the col1 i put the same for all is by mistake they should been col1, col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,

Comment: Then I don't understand you. You say "I want this one-row data to split into a multi column". OK, it's data from one row, but you also want to split it to multiple columns which implies tat currently the data is stored, in the format shown, in one column. If this is not the case, please edit the question showing properly a) the column definitions of the table and b) what are he contents of each column in the table.

Comment: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Thoughts on string splitting from Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: The question is clear I think, I would like to make this 1234 |abcd | 123abc | some | more | 0922 into separate columns. 1234 in one col1, abcd in col2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), left(row, charindex('|', row + '|') - 1)) as val,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(row, 1, charindex('|', row) + 1, '')) as rest,
             1 as lev, row
      from (values ('1234 |abcd | 123abc | some | more | 0922')) v(row)
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(rest, charindex('|', rest + '|') - 1)) as val,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(rest, 1, charindex('|', rest + '|') + 1, '')) as rest,
             lev + 1 as lev, row
      from cte
      where lev < 5 and rest <> ''
     )
select max(case when lev = 1 then val end) as col1,
       max(case when lev = 2 then val end) as col2,
       max(case when lev = 3 then val end) as col3,
       max(case when lev = 4 then val end) as col4,
       max(case when lev = 5 then val end) as col5
from cte
group by row;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e8e59673a0dca8ca3076f4d2209bb8e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff, this works perfectly the way I want it. you are the best. i have voted up for this as well.

Comment: Thank you all of you who participate in the discussion as well.